# compiler error xcode undeclared identifier c++

Tags: c++, c, xcode, undeclared-identifier

Hey Im writing a piece of code that reads in a file with cell vertices and cell vertices coordinates and prints out cell centres into a file.

I have 2 questions:

1: Im getting a red error in XCODE at the call to Print_Values subroutine, that says outfil is an undeclared identifier?? Although I identify the file right at the start of my main function??

2: Is there anyway this code can be optimised or vectorized either for conciseness or speed, Id greatly appreciate any pointers as this is my first program in a real programming language (I came from matlab)?? (for example I have 2 get values subroutines one that uses atoi for reading ints and the other strtod for reading doubles, I cant think of a way to turn these into one??)

edit: Using cygwin gcc-c++ compiler -std=c++11

Cheers and Many Thanks

Code so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

std::vector<double> GetValues_n(const std::vector<std::string>& src, int start, int end)
{
    std::vector<double> ret;
    for(int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        ret.push_back(std::strtod(src[i].c_str(), nullptr));
    }
    return ret;
}

std::vector<int> GetValues_c(const std::vector<std::string>& src, int start, int end)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    for(int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        ret.push_back(std::atoi(src[i].c_str()));
    }
    return ret;
}

std::vector<double> polycentre(const std::vector<double>&  x,const std::vector<double>&  y,size_t ID)
{
    std::vector<double> C(3, 0);
    std::vector<double> x1(x.size(),0);
    std::vector<double> y1(y.size(),0);
    size_t sizx = x.size();
    size_t sizy = y.size();
    if(sizy != sizx)
    {
        std::cerr << "polycentre inputs not equal length";
    }
    double x0 = x[0];
    double y0 = y[0];
    for(int aa = 1; aa < sizx; ++aa)
    {
        if(x[aa] < x0){x0 = x[aa];}
        if(y[aa] < y0){y0 = y[aa];}
    }
    double A = 0.0;
    double B = 0.0;
    for(size_t aa = 0; aa < sizx; ++aa)
    {
        x1[aa] = x[aa] - x0;
        y1[aa] = y[aa] - x0;
        if(aa != sizx-1)
        {
            A = A + (x1[aa]*y1[aa+1] - x1[aa+1]*y1[aa]);
            B = B + ((x1[aa]+x1[aa+1])*(x1[aa]*y1[aa-1]-x1[aa-1]*y1[aa]));
        }
        else if(aa == sizx-1)
        {
            A = A + (x1[aa] - y1[aa]);
            B = B + ((x1[aa]+1)*(x1[aa]*1-1*y1[aa]));
        }
    }
    A = A*0.5;
    C[0] = ID;
    C[1] = ((1/6/A)*B)+x0;
    C[2] = ((1/6/A)*B)+y0;
    return C;
}

template <typename T>

void PrintValues(const std::string& title, std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v, std::ofstream outfil)
{
    if(outfil.is_open())
    {
        outfil << "ID,X,Y,Z \n";
        std::cout << title << std::endl;
        for(size_t line = 0; line < v.size(); ++line)
        {
            for(size_t val = 0; val < v[line].size(); ++val)
            {
                std::cout << v[line][val] << " ";
                outfil << v[line][val] << ",";
            }
            outfil << "\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << argv[0] << " needs to get input file (2dm)" << std::endl;
    }

    else if (argc == 3)
    {
        std::ofstream outfil(argv[2]);
    }

    else
    {
        std::ofstream outfil(std::string(argv[1]) + ".csv");
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> values;
    std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(fin, line); )
    {
        std::istringstream in(line);
        values.push_back(
                         std::vector<std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                                                  std::istream_iterator<std::string>()));
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> cells;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> nodes;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(values[i][0] == "E3T")
        {
            cells.push_back(GetValues_c(values[i], 1, 5));
        }
        else if(values[i][0] == "E4Q")
        {
            cells.push_back(GetValues_c(values[i], 1, 6));
        }
        else if(values[i][0] == "ND")
        {
            nodes.push_back(GetValues_n(values[i], 1, 4));
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> cell_centres;

    for (size_t aa = 0; aa < cells.size(); ++aa)
    {
        if(cells[aa].size() == 5)
        {
            std::vector<double> xs = {nodes[(cells[aa][1]) - 1][1], nodes[(cells[aa][2]) - 1][1], nodes[(cells[aa][3]) - 1][1]};
            std::vector<double> ys = {nodes[(cells[aa][1]) - 1][2], nodes[(cells[aa][2]) - 1][2], nodes[(cells[aa][3]) - 1][2]};
            cell_centres.push_back(polycentre(xs,ys,aa+1));
        }
        else if(cells[aa].size() == 6)
        {
            std::vector<double> xs = {nodes[(cells[aa][1]) - 1][1], nodes[(cells[aa][2]) - 1][1], nodes[(cells[aa][3]) - 1][1], nodes[(cells[aa][4]) - 1][1]};
            std::vector<double> ys = {nodes[(cells[aa][1]) - 1][2], nodes[(cells[aa][2]) - 1][2], nodes[(cells[aa][3] - 1)][2], nodes[(cells[aa][4]) - 1][2]};
            cell_centres.push_back(polycentre(xs,ys,aa+1));
        }
    }

    PrintValues("Cell Centres", cell_centres, outfil);
    //PrintValues("Cells", cells, outfil);
    //PrintValues("Nodes", nodes, outfil);

    return 0;
}
```

The input file:

```
MESH2D
MESHNAME "default coverage"
NUM_MATERIALS_PER_ELEM 1 
E4Q 1 19 20 14 16 2
E4Q 2 17 16 15 23 2
E4Q 3 22 15 14 21 2
E4Q 4 4 3 21 20 1
E4Q 5 6 20 19 7 1
E4Q 6 18 17 10 9 1
E4Q 7 17 23 12 11 1
E4Q 8 7 19 18 8 1
E4Q 9 22 1 13 23 1
E3T 10 14 20 21 2
E3T 11 21 2 22 1
E3T 12 21 3 2 1
E3T 13 22 2 1 1
E3T 14 5 20 6 1
E3T 15 20 5 4 1
E3T 16 16 14 15 2
E3T 17 23 13 12 1
E3T 18 22 23 15 2
E3T 19 17 11 10 1
E3T 20 17 18 16 2
E3T 21 8 18 9 1
E3T 22 18 19 16 2
ND 1 -3.25811078e+002 7.70285567e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 2 -3.24209146e+002 7.60394871e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 3 -3.23012110e+002 7.44783503e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 4 -3.22754089e+002 7.25326647e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 5 -3.23617358e+002 7.08079432e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 6 -3.25161538e+002 6.98134116e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 7 -3.27128620e+002 6.98759747e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 8 -3.29095703e+002 6.99385378e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 9 -3.30301095e+002 7.14667646e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 10 -3.30786908e+002 7.33241555e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 11 -3.30835733e+002 7.52916270e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 12 -3.29587322e+002 7.65401204e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 13 -3.27743000e+002 7.72270000e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 14 -3.26108525e+002 7.32067724e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 15 -3.27041416e+002 7.42070316e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 16 -3.27350377e+002 7.31716751e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 17 -3.29153676e+002 7.40024406e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 18 -3.28659180e+002 7.19967464e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 19 -3.26845856e+002 7.14062637e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 20 -3.25000347e+002 7.20534611e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 21 -3.24701329e+002 7.39638966e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 22 -3.26167714e+002 7.53360591e+001 0.00000000e+000
ND 23 -3.28060316e+002 7.54194849e+001 0.00000000e+000
BEGPARAMDEF
GM  "Mesh"
SI  0
DY  0
TU  ""
TD  0  0
NUME  3
BCPGC  0
DISP_OPTS entity   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
DISP_OPTS inactive 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
DISP_OPTS multiple 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
BEFONT  0 1
DISP_OPTS entity   1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
DISP_OPTS inactive 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
DISP_OPTS multiple 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
BEFONT  1 1
DISP_OPTS entity   2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
DISP_OPTS inactive 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
DISP_OPTS multiple 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
BEFONT  2 1
MAT 1 "material 01"
MAT 2 "material 02"
MAT_MULTI 0
ENDPARAMDEF
BEG2DMBC
END2DMBC
BEGCURVE Version: 1
ENDCURVE
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables live inside the block where they are declared. That is, you `std::ofstream` in

```
...
else if (argc == 3)
{
    std::ofstream outfil(argv[2]);
}
...
```

is constructed and immediately destroyed as the block in which exists closes immediately after it gets define. You'll need to get the stream outside the block, e.g., by defining it first and then opening it when you know the file name:

```
std::ofstream outfil;
...
else if (argc == 3)
{
    outfil.open(argv[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* to use a single read function to read both doubles and integers: just always use `strtod` and read your numbers as `double`.

However: there is a huge functional difference between these two types of numbers as to how you are *using* them. The integers are indexes, and the double values are coordinates. Since you cannot use doubles as indexes, they would need to be cast to int before every use. That does not lead to "optimized code", but rather the exact opposite!

"More code overhead" -- in this case, functional code that reads, stores, and uses numbers in the most appropriate type for their function -- does *not* automatically equal to "less optimized code".

You could write a template for the reading code but the compiled result will be the same as what you have now.

If you need one particular routine -- reading from an external file and parsing the result -- to be fast, then read the entire data file into memory, process, and discard. You still need `strtod` and `atoi` (any code you would come up with yourself is probably slower) but you can write a simple string scanner that loops over the data once.
But you should only consider this if *reading* is a bottleneck.

Offhand I don't see any optimizations in the calculating part stand out. The only thing you could do is store the minimum values immediately while reading in your `Getvalue_C` routine.

But beware premature optimization! To see where your code is "slow", use a profiler.